# javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create an ImageInputStream in Tomcat 9, OpenJDK 11 and Geoserver

Tags: java, tomcat, geoserver, javax.imageio, java-11

While dealing with a *javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create an ImageInputStream!* after calling *ImageIO.read(File file)* because of a missing *FileImageInputStreamSpi* provider I recognized that the *ImageIO* service providers being available in my webapp depends on the fact whether a Geoserver (http://geoserver.org) webapp is running in the same Tomcat web container or not:

**Only my webapp running:**

- *Service provider that instantiates a FileImageInputStream from a RandomAccessFile*
- *Service provider that instantiates a FileImageInputStream from a File*
- *Service provider that instantiates a FileCacheImageInputStream or MemoryCacheImageInputStream from an InputStream*

**My webapp running along Geoserver 2.15.0 webapp:**

- *NIO Channel ImageInputStream*
- *Service provider that wraps a FileImageInputStream*
- *Service provider that helps connecting to the object pointed by a String*
- *Service provider that helps connecting to the object pointed by a URL*
- *Service provider that instantiates a FileImageInputStream from a RandomAccessFile*

Code in my webapp:

```
IIORegistry reg = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
Iterator<ImageInputStreamSpi> it = reg.getServiceProviders(ImageInputStreamSpi.class, true);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    ImageInputStreamSpi spi = it.next();
    System.out.println(spi.getDescription(Locale.GERMAN));
}
```

I'm using Tomcat 9.0.16 webapp and OpenJDK 11.

I wonder why both webapps may interfere in this way - isn't it actually a security issue?

Thank you for some general clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known issue with `ImageIO` and the `IIORegistry`. The registry instance is shared between all applications across the VM. And this often causes problems, like in your case.

I've written a little about [Deploying ImageIO plugins in a Web App](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app) in the readme for the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO project. Using the context listener may help with some problems, but it does not fix the underlying problem.

Another fix, is to deploy ImageIO plugins only as part of the server itself (ie. shared lib folder), to make sure all web apps sees the same plugins.

---

If you look deep in the source code of `IIORegistry` you'll see that it actually has some support for multiple registries, but these are tied to `AppContext`s (used by applets, webstart etc), which unfortunately is not the same as a web application context. It does seem like it should be possible to make the web contexts have different `AppContext`s too, if only they used different `ThreadGroup`s. But I have never found a way to make an app server assign a different thread group to each web application context.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and valuable answer! I for myself don't deploy any ImageIO plugins, I just want to use them. But obviously, Geoserver does deploy some. I'm not sure if the Geoserver team is aware of the interference you mentioned - maybe it's worth to file a bug including a link to the ContextListener workaround you proposed?

Comment: @user27772 I guess it can't hurt. :-)

Comment: if it is an issue just run two tomcats